# Can't communicate out of VM instance for Modbus TCP/IP over port 8080 - routes poosibly required

Tags: routing, port-forwarding, tcpip, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have used Google Cloud Developers Console to set up a Windows 2012 Server.
I am trying to use this a web server for monitoring hardware utilising Modbus TCP/IP.
I have installed a SCADA software package which uses port 8080 on the Windows Server to communicate via Modbus TCP/IP.
I have a hardware device which I want to communicate to on it's own port 503.

I have SCADA software running on a desktop PC and communicating via the appropriate ports to my hardware device so everything is compatible etc....

In the Windows Server I have attempted to allow firewall exceptions for port 8080 TCP/IP comms & even disabled the firewall - but I cannot seem to communicate out from the instance.

From what I understand I also need to set up routes to allow this all to happen.
This is something I a haven't come across before.

I can ping IP addresses from the windows server and I can ping to my servers external IP from outside the network.

The windows server has an external IP 104.197.x.x and the instance or Virtual Machine has another IP address 10.240.x.x

I hope this makes sense to you! That's about the gist of it all. I don't think it should be too difficult a task -- just something I have no knowledge on.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open the port & protocol on the Google Compute Engine firewall as well.

From the Developers Console, go to `Networking` -> `Firewall rules` -> click on the `New firewall rule`. Create a new firewall rule and open inbound traffic for tcp:8080

Comment: I have this done with the source being 0.0.0.0/0 but still no joy.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? It seems that the [default port number](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/connectedgrid/cgs2520/software/release/12_2_53_ex/configuration/guide/scg2520/swmodbus.html) is 502